# Type with required key and other mutual exclusive keys

Tags: typescript

```
export type EnvironmentKey = 
  { key: string } &
  ({ required?: true; } | { defaultValue?: string; });
```

How can I fix this type so that an `EnvironmentKey` can have either `required: true` or `defaultValue: ...`, or neither, but never both?

See it in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA7AbgSyhDAW2AxgGlhE4BeOAKDjgG84BrSgLjgGcYocMAczgBfOADIGcABQsowAI4BXPMAAmAfi58lwANyi4AH2Zw1wAGYBDJQBsYANSu3dWnnwGCDIgJR66dADGBLxwghAQagBKiiryalyYuPhEJOSUNKbsiFwARBYRuQA0cPLKqgkIULqiQSHw4ZEAIpY29onYeATEpBRUtCzZeQUQxWatdo7OunkAFji5tcEYoY1qAHLAODCzwFAdyd1pfZmDnHD5haL+dAD0t3AAKvPcPLMQdmpw1ji2dSvwABGVjUACEIDsDl1Ur0MgM2OdLqMSmU4uptNVgCVzNZJk4XMA5gsREA). (See `badBoth`.)